# SVG pan and zoom JS-plugin fires strange error?

Tags: javascript, svg, plugins

Im using the script from ariutta

[Demo from ariutta](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/embed.html)

[script from ariutta](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom)

The provided online demo just works fine but whenever I try to implement it in my local test it won't work. I thought it may be due the big svg file size, so I added a button to initialize the zoom and pan controls. When I hit the button the logs appear.

I collected all the different Browser Error Logs:

Chrome 79.0.3945.130:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'queryCommandSupported' on 'Document': queryCommandSupported is only supported on HTML documents.
    at chrome-extension://fbcohnmimjicjdomonkcbcpbpnhggkip/contentscripts/toolbarContentscript.js:5:42
adult-content.js:66 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at apologizeHangers (adult-content.js:66)
    at adult-content.js:111
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at adult-content.js:110
svg-pan-zoom.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
    at Object.getSvg (svg-pan-zoom.min.js:3)
    at p (svg-pan-zoom.min.js:3)
    at enablePANandZOOM (embed.html:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (embed.html:10)
```

Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0

```
0: Zugriff verweigert(access denied translated)           svg-pan-zoom.min.js (2,28301)
```

IE11 11.973.17763.0

```
SCRIPT5: Zugriff verweigert(access denied translated)
svg-pan-zoom.min.js (3,28302)
```

Firefox 72.0.1 (64-Bit)

```
TypeError: e.getSVGDocument(...) is nullsvg-pan-zoom.min.js:3:28306
    getSvg http://georodin.de/svg-pan-zoom.min.js:3
    p http://georodin.de/svg-pan-zoom.min.js:3
    enablePANandZOOM file:///C:/Users/***/Desktop/SpaceCitizen2D/embed.html:16
    onclick file:///C:/Users/***/Desktop/SpaceCitizen2D/embed.html:1
```

This is the content of the `embed.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://georodin.de/svg-pan-zoom.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Demo for svg-pan-zoom: SVG in HTML 'embed' element</h1>
    <button onclick="enablePANandZOOM()">Enable Zoom</button>
    <embed id="demo-tiger" type="image/svg+xml" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px solid black; " src="http://georodin.de/background_1.svg" />

    <script>
      function enablePANandZOOM() {
        svgPanZoom('#demo-tiger', {
          zoomEnabled: true,
          controlIconsEnabled: true
        });
      };


    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

The SVG is properly displayed but the controls don't appear. Also im not able to pan the SVG like in the provided demo.

Comment: You need to serve your page on georodin.de too. You can't access any other files from a filesystem page.

Comment: This does work. Any chance to get it to run locally too? Replacing the paths to local files did not work. So I guess its something inside the svg-pan-zoom.min.js

Comment: You could run your own local web server and deploy the files there.